# Dafny Question: What's the cause of this verification timeout?

Tags: dafny

```
predicate DivideBy2(x: int)
{
    x % 2 == 0
}

predicate DivideBy4(x: int)
{
    x % 4 == 0
}

predicate DivideBy3(x: int)
{
    x % 3 == 0
}

method test()
    ensures DivideBy3(12)
{
    assert forall x: int | DivideBy4(x) :: DivideBy2(x);
    assert forall x: int :: DivideBy4(x) ==> DivideBy2(x);
}
```

The verification failed because it 'timed out after 20 seconds'.
However, the post-condition can be proved if the two assertions inside the body are removed. Also, it can be proved if the post-condition is stated as an assertion inside the body.

My question is

1. What's the cause of the timeout verification here?
2. The assertions used inside the body are highly abstract, as they don't give a bound to the input range. How does Dafny verify such logic?
3. Is there any difference between the two assertions used in the body? To me, it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dafny (more accurately underlying z3 solver) uses heuristics to reason about assertions. Since these are heuristics sometimes search wanders off in wrong direction and dafny is not able to find validity of assert statement in verification time limit. It requires hints to stay on course like shown below

```
predicate DivideBy2(x: int)
{
  x % 2 == 0
}

predicate DivideBy4(x: int)
{
  x % 4 == 0
}

predicate DivideBy3(x: int)
{
  x % 3 == 0
}

method test()
  ensures DivideBy3(12)
{
  forall x: int | DivideBy4(x) ensures DivideBy2(x)  {
    if(DivideBy4(x)){
      assert 4 * (x / 4) + x % 4 == x;
      assert 4 * (x / 4) == x;
      assert 2 * (2 * (x / 4)) == x;
    }
  }
  assert forall x : int | DivideBy4(x) :: DivideBy2(x);
  assert forall x : int :: DivideBy4(x) ==> DivideBy2(x);
}
```

Regarding question 3, these two are different ways to write same thing.

Comment: Could you please explain your code? To me, it's like "for every x which satisfies DivideBy4(x)==>DivideBy2(x), if DivideBy4(x), then assertions." And the origin assertions written by me mean "for every x if DivideBy4(x) then DivideBy2(x)". To me, it shows a different meaning.

Comment: I have modified my code to make it more cleaner. But are n't they saying same thing. I need only have to take care of case DivideBy4(x) to prove DivideBy4(x) ==> DivideBy2(x)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! Could you please introduce how you chose hints when you see the verification timeout (or similar situations)?

Comment: Dafny reference manual (http://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef) has section on Verification debugging when verification fails it guides you things to try to make verification pass